# How to know if an agument is a directory or file in Java

Tags: java, file, directory

I am trying to pass an argument to a method . The argument can be a file or a direcotry.

```
public class ReadCsv {

    String line =  null;
    BufferedReader br ;

    public void readCsv(String arg) throws Exception{

        File file = new File(arg);
        if(file.isDirectory()){
        for(File dir : file.listFiles()){

                System.out.println(file.getName());
                reader(dir);
            }
        }
        else{
                reader(file);

            }
        }

    public void reader(File file) throws Exception {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            //Code 
    }
}
```

But the code is not working as I want to. When I pass an argument `arg` , I have to determine whether it is a file or a directory and work according to it . Can anyone please help me how to determine a file or a directory .This code of mine runs the loop 4 times if arg is a directory.

Comment: Isn't it funny that you already have the desired functionality (i.e. File#isDirectory) in the method readCsv?

Comment: Your ARG is DIR than ,
1> May be there are other directory under that DIR  
2> you are sure that Under DIR (if is directory) all are file .
For first case I have post my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, looks like you're just outputting the directory (which you have named 'file') instead of the file, which you have named 'dir'.

```
for(File dir : file.listFiles()) {
   System.out.println(dir.getName()); //you were outputting file.getName()
}
```

Comment: Also as ankit337 says, it's not recursive so it wont deal with nested directories.

Answer (score 1):

`File` has `isDirectory()` and `isFile()` methods you can use to check the type.

Answer (score 1):

See [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) official documentation. There are methods such as:

```
isFile();
isDirectory();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try It .. 
It print all Directories and file name .

IF Nested Directories :

```
public class ReadCsv {

    String line =  null;
    BufferedReader br ;

    public void readCsv(String arg) throws Exception{

        File file = new File(arg);
        checkIsDir(file );
    }

    public void checkIsDir(File file) throws Exception {

       if(file.isDirectory()){

            System.out.println("Directory : "file.getName());
            for(File dir : file.listFiles()){
                  checkIsDir(dir);
            }
        }
        else{
                System.out.println("File : "file.getName());
                reader(file);    
            }
    }

    public void reader(File file) throws Exception {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            //Code 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a code improvement (to include nested directories) which happens to fix the error in question (outputting the directory name multiple times) without explanation.  So not really an answer.

Comment: `@Ross..` I already have make comment under question  that is used for Nested Directories . Also now make some edit here . Thanks